# Cancel a header(refresh)

Tags: php, header, http-redirect, cancellation

Is it possible to cancel this after calling it:

```
<?php
// Start output while creating profile
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<1; $i++)
{
    // Redirect user and download the profile
    header('Refresh: .02; download.php');
    echo "You're profile is being created, please wait...";

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}

ob_end_flush();

// Start creating the profile
// Start this after the code above due to the long execution time
if(!createProfile())
{
    // If createProfile returns false, cancel redirect and stop execution
    cancelRedirect();
    // Inform the user about the problem
    echo 'Error!';
    exit;
}
?>
```

The intention is that the `header()`-function is called, then the script does something and if the result is not as expected the redirect to "download.php" should be cancelled.

Comment: Logically, it makes no sense.

Comment: That's the only way to do that because `echo` something before calling the `header()` function doesn't work.

Comment: There is `header_remove()` though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but output buffering may be your answer.

Comment: "*That's the only way to do that*" @alve89 - No it's surely not. As was pointed out in the *answer* below, it makes more logical sense to send your headers *only* if certain conditions are met. Not to send them unconditionally, then attempt to retract them afterwards. And in regards to outputting data prior to sending headers: there are easy ways around that issue as well by running any/all logic *prior* to `echo`'ing anything that might result in headers being sent.

Comment: You're right, it is absolutely more logical to `echo` something after the logic. But after a couple of time I had no more ideas how to solve the problem:
`echo` something to inform the user about the long execution time (logically before executing the problematic code) and then redirect him to another page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible but the reverse is possible:

```
<?php
    if (doSomething()) {
        header('Refresh: 1; download.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Of course this is possible - but unfortunately this doesn't help me. Was that possible with JavaScript?

Comment: Looks like it is an X-Y problem here... Tell us the full issue, so that we can guide you something better. @alve89...

Comment: I try: I'm creating a configuration profile that contains data like mail accounts, calendar accounts, etc. This is quite time-consuming, so I'd like to inform the user that the profile is being created (that's much better than a loading blank page, isn't it?). After the profile has been successfully created I'd like to redirect the user to a page that downloads the file. I also edited / updated the main question.

Was that understandable?